# Why is the validation accuracy constant at 20%?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a 5 class animal classifier using Keras. I am building the CNN from scratch and the weird thing is,  the validation accuracy stays constant at 0.20 for all epochs. Any idea why this is happening? The dataset folder contains train, test and validation folders. And each of the folders contains 5 folders corresponding to the 5 classes. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried multiple optimizer but the problem persists. I have included the code sample below.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#First convolution layer
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

#Second convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

#Flatten the outputs of the convolution layer into a 1D contigious array
model.add(Flatten())

#Add a fully connected layer containing 256 neurons
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#Add another fully connected layer containing 256 neurons
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#Add the ouput layer containing 5 neurons, because we have 5 categories
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

optim=RMSprop(lr=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optim,metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

#We will use the below code snippet for rescaling the images to 0-1 for all the train and test images
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#We won't augment the test data. We will just use ImageDataGenerator to rescale the images.
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                    classes=['frog', 'giraffe', 'horse', 'tiger','dog'],
                                                    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    shuffle=False)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                        classes=['frog', 'giraffe', 'horse', 'tiger','dog'],
                                                        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='categorical',
                                                        shuffle=False)
hist=History()

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
                    callbacks=[hist])

model.save('models/basic_cnn_from_scratch_model.h5') #Save the model weights #Load using: model = load_model('cnn_from_scratch_weights.h5') from keras.models import load_model
print("Time taken to train the baseline model from scratch: ",datetime.now()-global_start)
```

Comment: Try to increase learning rate to `1e-2` or `1e-3`. And maybe decrease `Dense` to 128, depending on the size and variance of your dataset. Also, the `#Second convolution layer` input_shape must come from First Convolution layer output, not input_shape itself.

Comment: I tried both the approaches you have mentioned, the training accuracy increased to 90%, but the validation accuracy is still stuck at 20%. I also tried with 3 classes and the validation accuracy remained constant at 33%. Is it something do with the class labels?

Comment: Do you have an imbalanced dataset ? Like a minority class too small ?

Comment: Nopes. The dataset is perfectly balanced!

Answer (score 2):

Check the following for your data:

1. Shuffle the training data well (I see `shuffle=False` everywhere)
2. Properly normalize all data (I see you are doing `rescale=1./255`, maybe okay)
3. Proper train/val split (you seem to be doing that too)

Suggestions for your model:

1. Use multiple `Conv2D` layers followed by a final `Dense`. That's what works best for image classification problems. You can also look at popular architectures that are tried and tested; e.g. AlexNet
2. Can change the optimizer to `Adam` and try with different learning rates
3. Have a look at your training and validation loss graphs and see if they look as expected

Also, I guess you corrected the shape of the 2nd `Conv2D` layer as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the shape for the 2nd Conv2D layer. I will provide an update today after trying few other things. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. Changing the optimzer to adam made it work! However, the model is overfitted to the train set. The loss values diverges after 10 epochs. I will have to use some aggressive dropout strategies to tackle this.

Comment: You can add `Dropout` layers between `Dense` layers. Did you change the architecture of your model, btw?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your output is always the same animal, thus you have a 20% accuracy. I highly recommend you to check your testing outputs to see if they are all the same.

Also you said that you were building a CNN but in the code snipet you posted I see only dense layers, it is going to be hard for a dense architecture to do this task, and it is very small. What is the size of your pictures?

Hope it helps!

Comment: There are two Convolution layers at the start and 3 dense layers after that. The dataset contains 10000 images for training, 2500 for validation and another 2500 for testing. That means 2000 images for each classes for training and 500 each for validation and testing. I was successfully able to train a model using bottleneck features of the same dataset. The test accuracy is 95%. However, while training a convent from scratch, the accuracy get's stuck at 20%.

Comment: Image dimensions are 256*256.

Comment: Definitely use shuffle as other answer suggested. Check as I said in my anwser that you are not always outputting the same number. Change the optimizer to adam and increase a little bit the learning rate. I think you have too few convolutional layers. Some graphs from the train and test loss and acurracy could be useful to give you more feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give you the graph outputs very soon. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No prob, we are here to help!

Answer (score 1):

The models seems to be working now. I have removed shuffle=False attribute. Corrected the input shape for the 2nd convolution layer. Changed the optimizer to adam. I have reached a validation accuracy of almost 94%. However, I have not yet tested the model on unseen data. There is a bit of overfitting in the model. I will have to use some aggressive dropouts to reduce them. Thanks!